# Java - How to detect IP version

Tags: java, servlets, network-programming

I'm getting `Client` IP address via below method :

```
public static String getClientIpAddr(HttpServletRequest request) {  
    String ip = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");  
    ...
    return ip
}
```

Now I want to detect if it is an `IPV4` or an `IPV6`.

Comment: You can use regex as stated here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/DetermineifthegivenstringisavalidIPv4orIPv6address.htm

Comment: Be aware that unless X-Forwarded-For is set by some of *your* server (Like  BigIP F5) it cannot be trusted as it can be set by client to anything.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You could create an InetAddress and check if it became an ipv4 or ipv6 instance

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
if (address instanceof Inet6Address) {
    // It's ipv6
} else if (address instanceof Inet4Address) {
    // It's ipv4
}
```

It seems a bit awkward, though, and I hope there is a better solution.

Comment: Better how? It relies on the JDK rather than a home-grown regex. Seems OK to me.

Comment: Better in that it doesn't rely on instanceof. It would be nice to have a method in InetAddress that returns a constant to indicate the version being used.

Answer (score 10):

If you are sure you're getting either an IPv4 or IPv6, you can try the following. If you have a DNS name then this will try to perform a lookup. Anyway, try this:

```
try {

    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(myIpAddr);

    if (address instanceof Inet4Address) {
        // your IP is IPv4
    } else if (address instanceof Inet6Address) {
        // your IP is IPv6
    }

} catch(UnknownHostException e) {

    //  your address was a machine name like a DNS name, and couldn't be found

}
```

Comment: please change the `Inet4Address` to `Inet6Address` in the `else` part.

Answer (score 5):

You can use InetAddresses from google guava. For example like this:

```
int addressLength = InetAddresses.forString(ip).getAddress().length;
switch (addressLength) {
    case 4:
        System.out.println("IPv4");
        break;
    case 16:
        System.out.println("IPv6");
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect ip address length " + addressLength);
}
```

Comment: I like this idea, thanks! It works with standard Java API as well: java.net.InetAddress.getByName(ip).getAddress().length

Comment: @YannVo Yes, it works but I'm affraid to use  `java.net.InetAddress` because they usually try to invoke some system functions like forward/reverse name resolutions. Usually it's a pain to test code with InetAddress inside